# Select rows where the string in one column is an extension of a string in another column

Tags: sql

The question: Find the capital and the name where the capital is an extension of name of the country.
Note that the capital must be longer than the name (Mexico-City compared to Luxembourg)
This is my work, but it's incorrect

```
SELECT name , capital
FROM world
WHERE capital LIKE concat(name, '%')
```

Comment: You could just add - `AND LEN(Capital) > LEN(name)`, or `Capital <> name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the extension you can use REPLACE function which in following query replacing the 'name' of country from 'capital' to null.

```
SELECT name , REPLACE(capital,name,'')
FROM world
WHERE capital LIKE concat(name, '_%');
```

Comment: You could improve the quality of this answer with a plain-english explanation of what the code is doing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This is working for me.

```
SELECT name, capital
FROM world
WHERE capital LIKE concat(name, '%') AND capital <> name;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT capital, name
FROM world
WHERE capital LIKE concat(name, '%') or capital LIKE concat(name, ' %')
```

Correct ^_^

Answer (score 1):

```
select name,capital
from world
where capital like concat(name,'%') and capital <> name;
```

Output:

```
name    capital
Andorra Andorra la Vella
Guatemala   Guatemala City
Kuwait  Kuwait City
Mexico  Mexico City
Monaco  Monaco-Ville
Panama  Panama City
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

The `LEN()` function returns the length of the value in a text field.

```
SELECT name , capital
FROM world
WHERE capital LIKE concat(name, '%')
AND LEN(Capital) > LEN(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT capital, name
FROM world
WHERE capital LIKE concat('%',name, '%')
```

This is the most inclusive way to write the code. It could be written more concisely to

```
SELECT capital, name
FROM world
WHERE capital LIKE concat(name, '%')
```

It is the case with capital names that the country always comes first, e.g. Mexico City rather than City of Mexico--at least in the English language.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, capital  
FROM world   
WHERE capital LIKE concat('%', name, '%')  
AND LENGTH(capital) > LENGTH(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT capital, name
FROM world
WHERE capital LIKE CONCAT(name, '%') 
AND name != capital
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name 
FROM world
WHERE capital LIKE concat(name, ' city')
```

Comment: This would fail to find the sample "Mexico-City" and also wouldn't find other cases that don't end in "city" (as "city" isn't a requirement, just that the name is longer)